# How to smartly handle data from a mtp stack to a treewidget to display file

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qtreewidget, mtp

I'm writing an app to create a file browser of the FS of a MTP device. I have done a first version but I think I can make it better designed.

Current, I have a wrote a mtp_wrapper.cpp which provide a class mtp with different method inside to get files, get folders, delete files...

For example, My mainwindow class contain:

```
void MainWindow::DisplayTree(uint32_t index, uint32_t parent)
{
    LIBMTP_file_t *files;
    LIBMTP_file_t *file;

    MyTree->clear();

  //  files = m_device.GetFileAndFolder(index);
    if(files == NULL)
        return;

    file = files;
    while(file != NULL && file->parent_id == parent) {
        LIBMTP_file_t *oldfile;

        QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        if(strcmp(file->filename,"Android") == 0)
            item->setText(0,"AneedA");
        else
            item->setText(0,file->filename);

        if (file->filetype == LIBMTP_FILETYPE_FOLDER) {
            item->setText(1, "--");
            item->setText(2, "--");
            DisplaySubTree(item, file->item_id);
        }
        else {
            const QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromTime_t(file->modificationdate);
            const QString textdate = dt.toString( Qt::TextDate );
            item->setText(1,textdate);
            item->setText(2, QString::number(file->filesize));
        }
        MyTree->addTopLevelItem(item);
        oldfile = file;
        file = file->next;
#if 0
        m_device.DestroyFile(oldfile);
#endif
    }
}
```

The first call of this, is using (0,0) as argument to display the whole tree. but I think it's not smart enough. The DisplayTree method should only called a list and there is no need to have a call to mtp_api.

I know that gtk have some method to store_list, set_list and reuse it but I'm currently under Qt and C++

Any idea, I can disconnect the mainwindow from the mtp ? The best should be to have the list/model filed by the mtp part. I have created an method used to scan the mtp device and the mainwindows through the tree method will reuse this list/model to display data.